# VBA Add rows based on how many times a criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA so my question may sound silly to some of you.

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to check between 2 sheets(1st: test and 2nd: test data. In the code I am using the code name of the sheets) how may times a criteria/my product is met and based on that number to add that many rows beneath the SKU/product.

What I want to do is, if for my first product/SKU I have stock in 5 different locations, I want to add 5 rows in the first sheet and to see the qty in column D and the location in column E.

[image]

[TestData tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZNwi.png)

[image]

The reason why I need to list the quantity in different cells is that the stock is in different locations, so I can not just add in to one cell.
I am also adding screen shots of how my two sheets look like.
I have not add the loop to find the location yet, but I want to understand how to add the rows first.

```
Sub test()

Dim myrange As Range, testrange As Range, cell As Range, result As Range
Dim i As Long, testlastrow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim helprng As Range

lastrow = TESTTAB.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
testlastrow = TDATA.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set testrange = TDATA.Range("a2:c" & testlastrow)
Set myrange = TESTTAB.Range("b2:b" & lastrow)
Set result = TESTTAB.Range("d2:e" & testlastrow)
Set helprng = TESTTAB.Range("f2:f" & lastrow)

For Each cell In myrange
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If cell.Cells(i, 1) = testrange.Cells(i, 1) Then
    result.Cells(i, 1) = testrange.Cells(i, 2)
    End If
Next i
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't exacly understood what you are trying to achieve, but have you considered a filter or a pivot table to obtain your data? Anyway to add a row you can use the Range.Insert method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert You can use a variable to count how many new rows you need and then insert as many rows as needed. You could also consider to cut and paste part of the list instead of inserting brand new rows (should be faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the raw structure you were asking for.

```
Sub test()
    ' 011

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim Radd As Long                            ' number of rows to add
    Dim R As Long                               ' row counter

    With Tdata
        ' Range, Cells and Rows Count, all in the same sheet
        ' exclude caption row(s)
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' speed up the process
    With TestTab
        ' end the loop in row 2 because row 1 might contain captions
        ' loop bottom to top because row numbers will change
        '   below the current row as you insert rwos
        ' column 1 = "A"
        For R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            Tmp = .Cells(R, 1).Value
            Radd = Application.CountIf(Rng, Tmp)
            If Radd > 1 Then
                .Range(.Rows(R + 1), .Rows(R + Radd)).Insert
                .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value = Radd   ' for testing purposes
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True           ' now you look
End Sub
```

As our Evil Blue Monkey has suggested, inserting blank rows and then populating them may not be the most efficient way. You can copy a row and then click `Insert` to insert the copied data into a new row. Get the syntax from the Macro recorder if it's of interest. It works with the Range object the same way.

Comment: Thank you Evil Blue Monkey and Variatus, you helped me big time!